# Is it possible to ask GIT, don't show a file?

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm facing a very annoying situation.

Our application contains Crashlytics in order to collect crashes and doing Analytic stuff. Crashlytics generates `crashlytics.properties` file and update it periodically. This file shouldn't be under version control and I cannot add it to `.gitignore` file since my team lead doesn't agree.

I added this file into git (by `git add`) and then asked git to don't track it by `git update-index --assume-unchanged crashlytics.propertise` command. I'm able to see it's status changed to `Added Unchanged (Assumed and Actually` on SmartGit tool.

My problem is this file is always visible and I cannot use `git add .` any more since this file will be added too :(

Is there any way to ask Git to don't show this file? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not allowed to add it to the `.gitignore` which is checked in you can still add `crashlytics.properties` to a local `.gitignore` or add it to your global ignore list. How to do that ist described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: A very nice hint. Thanks.

Comment: can you please have a look at this new question since my problem still not fixed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188740/file-after-adding-to-global-git-file-is-still-visible