# File after adding to global git file is still visible

Tags: git, gitignore

continue from my previous question [Is it possible to ask GIT, don't show a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186955/is-it-possible-to-ask-git-dont-show-a-file)

I have a file that I want to add it to global .gitignore that shouldn't be inside .gitignore of project.

I have added `excludesfile` path into my .gitconfig file

```
[user]
    name = Hesam
    email = MY-EMAIL-ADDRESS
[color]
    ui = true
    diff = true
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/admin/.gitignore_global
```

Then I added full path to the file that I don't want to track it in `.gitignore_global` file.

```
/Users/admin/Desktop/android/my-app/crashlytics.properties
```

Still, when I navigate to my project directory and enter `git status` my response is:

```
>> git status
On branch fix_confirm_booking
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    my-app/crashlytics.properties

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One possible explanation is that your Git installation is set up to use a global config file other that the `.gitconfig` file you mention. If you run `git config --global --list`, do you see the `core.excludesfile` entry in the output?

Comment: Thanks Jubobs, Yes, I see all those things such as user.name, user.email and core.excludesfile with theire values.

Comment: An alternative would be to add it to a local .gitignore in the repository where it is. If you don't want it in version control, add the .gitignore to itself.

Comment: Thanks @Trengot, As I mentioned in my previous question I am not allowed to add it to `.gitignore` file of project. That's why I'm adding it to global one.

Comment: You can add it locally but not commit the .gitignore file. The file won't be shown for you but will be for everyone else.

Comment: @Trengot, I tried to add it by `git add ` command. But if I commit it and create a new branch based on then when I push the branch this file will be pushed too. If I'm wrong please correct me. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to add it. It just needs to exist. Git will read it and ignore the files listed. If you list the gitignore file as well, git will pretend neither exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. Unfortunately Git doesn't rely on full/complete path. As soon as I replaced my full path with relative (actually is not relative) path then it worked.

What I did, I replaced my `.gitignore_global` contents from:

> /Users/admin/Desktop/android/my-app/crashlytics.properties

to

> my-app/crashlytics.properties